# Passing fragmentRootElementName as parameters to the xml

Tags: spring-batch

Is it possible to send fragmentRootElementName as a parameter to the job xml file. I have two processes one is plan and the other contract. So I divided my job into reading the file from database, converting it to an object and then publishing it in webservices. The reading part first reads a property file, there we get the info if the process is a plan or contract and accordingly we need to call the corresponding process. I did the one flow for plan but is it possible to pass the fragmentRootElementName as a prameter.. as it would be different for plan and contract

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can using [late-binding](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/reference/html-single/#late-binding) via `scope="step"` in this way:

```
<bean id="myReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemReader" scope="step">
  <property name="fragmentRootElementName" value="#{jobParameters['rootFragmentName']}" />
  <!-- Other properties -->
</bean>
```