# Jaxb Unmarshall with an unknown @XmlRootElement

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, unmarshalling

I cannot achieve to **unmarshall** an XML without knowing the root element. eg.

```
<foo>
   <bar/>
</foo>
```

or

```
<bar>
   <bar/>
</bar>
```

etc...

I want to map the unmarshalling result on a class like :

```
// @XmlRootElement ??
public class Container
    implements Serializable
{
    private Bar bar;
}
```

I am always required to fix the `@XmlRootElement`.
I searched how to set the @XmlRootElement at runtime without success. Any idea?

I am in Spring Batch context and I can use the unmarshaller of my choice.

Note : I cannot use `@XmlElementDecl` or an `ObjectFactory` as shown [here](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/07/jaxb-and-root-elements.html) because **I don't know the name of the possibles root names**.

Comment: What do you expect to be the end result of your unmarshalling?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have edited the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can JAXB handle multiple "root" elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12915968/can-jaxb-handle-multiple-root-elements)

Comment: Hmm, this post suppose that I know what the root element can be or I didn't get it? It's not my case, I don't know what the root name can be.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JAXB unmarshalling without XmlRootElement annotation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33823139/jaxb-unmarshalling-without-xmlrootelement-annotation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adapted his approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33824472/181336

```
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Test {

    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PROPERTY)
    public static class Bar {
        private String name;

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        @XmlElement
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
    }

    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PROPERTY)
    public static class Container implements Serializable {
        private Bar bar;

        public Bar getBar() {
            return bar;
        }

        @XmlElement
        public void setBar(Bar bar) {
            this.bar = bar;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Container.class);
        String xml = "<foo><bar><name>Barry</name></bar></foo>";
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes());
        JAXBElement<Container> barWrapperElement = unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StreamSource(is), Container.class);
        Container container = barWrapperElement.getValue();

        System.out.println(container.getBar().getName());
    }
}
```

It works!

Comment: So did you get it to work with multiple anonymous root elements?

Comment: Yes, thank you. In spring batch, I parametrized the `fragmentRootElementName`  of `StaxEventItemReader` using [late-binding](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18693233/3042945). This `fragmentRootElementName` is `foo` or `bar` in my example. `StaxEventItemReader` doesn't care about the root name of the document (eg `root`, `root2`).  I will do a post with the complete solution.

Answer (score 0):

Which ever XML your passing does have a root elements, xml which you mentioned have two file

```
<foo>
  <bar/>
</foo>
```

or

```
<bar>
 <bar/>
```

so here you have two root names foo or bar so create two classes for each if which ever root name it will call that class

Comment: I don't know in advance the name of the root. That' why I can't create a class using that name. The XML I mentionned is a minimalist version of what I really want to achieve.